# Table layout not fitting screen

Tags: java, android, background, tablelayout

I have an activity which creates a table dynamically. The activity is created and is working fine.

**This is the source code of the xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#142c57"
    tools:context=".TableActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/followup_list" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:padding="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:background="@drawable/inner_box">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                        <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/follow_up_table"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                            android:stretchColumns="0">


                        </TableLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The output of the xml file:**

[image: output]

**I want the table to fill the whole box, the space on the right hand side of the table is not required and is looking awkward. What is to be done to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **layout was required to be edited like this**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#142c57"
    tools:context=".TableActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/followup_list" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heading_textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:padding="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:background="@drawable/inner_box">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/follow_up_table"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                        android:stretchColumns="0,1">


                    </TableLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The **output**:

[image: Output]

Comment: Spotting the diff is not easy, let me spot it... 

      android:stretchColumns="0,1"

Answer (score 3):

Better yet stretch and shrink all columns to fit your screen with:

```
<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/follow_up_table"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:stretchColumns="*"
 android:shrinkColumns="*">

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table layout width wraps its content, it should be `match_parent`

```
<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/follow_up_table"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:stretchColumns="0">


</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the change as :

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/follow_up_table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:stretchColumns="0">
</TableLayout>
```

Change is :

```
android:layout_width="**fill_parent**"
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of using HorizontalScrollView? Just remove it and set TableLayout's android:layout_width to match_parent.